# After using DOTENV, server stops working in express generated by express generator

Tags: node.js, express

After including DOTENV the server stops working in express generated by **express generator**.

Here is how I include DOENV in app.js:-

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'variables.env' });
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

This is the error message I receive in the browser when I try to access a route:

---

> This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost refused to connect.
>   Search Google for localhost 3000 parties add
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

But if I remove this code:-

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'variables.env' });
```

It starts to work again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you can't post your .env file here as it likely has secrets in it (the whole point of a .env), but Likely one or more of the variables in it are wrong. Check to make sure you're not changing the PORT variable and that all your other connection related variables (e.g. Use of https, database URL and credentials, etc) are set to the correct value.

Also ensure that the path you've configured for your .env file is correct.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks! You are right! The port in my ENV file is 7777, while I use 3000 in the browser.